# determine what service is running a script

Tags: linux, process

I share a dev server with some colleagues, it's a Ubuntu server and we have several scripts there, so basically the usual way we run a process is using a `screen` session. My problem is that when I do `ps aux| grep python` I see a running process:

```
root     x  x  x x x x  Ss   Apr12  29:58 /usr/bin/python /home/script.py
```

this script is not being run on a screen session and it automatically starts when killed so I need to know what service is starting/restarting that process. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, PepperoniPizza, you can probably [audit all execve events](http://whmcr.com/2011/10/14/auditd-logging-all-commands/) which would give the the PID of the process that keeps spawning it and just follow the trail back to something you can recognize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pstree to get a tree view of the all the process along with their parents. In the following example I will get the parent process of pulseaudio, which have PID of 1913:

```
$ pstree -sU 1913   
systemd───pulseaudio─┬─{alsa-sink-ALC88}
                     └─{alsa-source-ALC}
```

In your case I would use pgrep plus pstree, like this:

```
pstree -sU $(pgrep /home/script.py)
```

Notice, that if the script parent was killed is highly likely that its parent will be init. In such case, you will need a more aggressive way to get the parent process.